# How to differentiate alarm between am and pm by using alarm manager?

Tags: android

I am creating alarm alert for appointment reminder for that I am using following code.Code is working very well it showing me alarm alert but only problem is that, it is not differentiate alarm between am and pm,  suppose if I set alarm for **7am** and currently **7pm** in device then also my alert dialog shows. How can I manage that am and pm? I used this link for ref

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/setting-up-alarm-using-alarmmanager-and-waking-up-screen-and-unlocking-keypad-on-alarm-goes-off-in-android/

AlertDemo.class

```
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
 import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;


public class AlertDemo extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Turn Screen On and Unlock the keypad when this alert dialog is     displayed */
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |   LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);


    /** Creating a alert dialog builder */
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    /** Setting title for the alert dialog */
    builder.setTitle("Alarm");

    /** Setting the content for the alert dialog */
    builder.setMessage("An Alarm by AlarmManager");

    /** Defining an OK button event listener */
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            /** Exit application on click OK */
            getActivity().finish();
        }                       
    });

    /** Creating the alert dialog window */
    return builder.create();
 }

 /** The application should be exit, if the user presses the back button */ 
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {      
    super.onDestroy();
    getActivity().finish();
 }
```

}

Appointment.class

```
  import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Calendar;
  import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.AlarmManager;
  import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
  import android.app.Dialog;
  import android.app.Notification;
  import android.app.NotificationManager;
  import android.app.PendingIntent;
  import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
  import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.DatePicker;
  import android.widget.TimePicker;
  import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Appointment extends Activity {

Button date, time, save;

private static final int DIALOG_DATE = 1;
private static final int DIALOG_TIME = 2;
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
int i;
String strmonth, strday, stryear;

String months[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

int intmonth, intday, intyear, inthour, intminutes;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
private SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.doctor_appointment);

    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsetdate);
    time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsettime);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
    timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    // c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4);

    date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DIALOG_DATE);
        }
    });
    time.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DIALOG_TIME);
        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.healthmanager.DemoActivity");
            /** Creating a Pending Intent */
            PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            /** Getting a reference to the System Service ALARM_SERVICE */
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            String strtime = time.getText().toString();

            Log.v("str btntime", strtime);

            String[] splitstrtime = strtime.split(":");

            Log.v("timestr1", splitstrtime[0]);
            Log.v("timestr2", splitstrtime[1]);

            int splithour = Integer.parseInt(splitstrtime[0]);
            String[] splitsecond = splitstrtime[1].split(" ");

            Log.v("split str second", splitsecond[0]);
            int splitmin = Integer.parseInt(splitsecond[0]);

            /**
             * Creating a calendar object corresponding to the date and time
             * set by the user
             */
            // GregorianCalendar calendar = new
            // GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, hour, minute);
            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(intyear,
                    intmonth, intday, splithour, splitmin);

            /**
             * Converting the date and time in to milliseconds elapsed since
             * epoch
             */
            long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            /** Setting an alarm, which invokes the operation at alart_time */
            alarmManager
                    .set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time, operation);

            /** Alert is set successfully */
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm is set successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

// For date dialog
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DATE:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                day);
    case DIALOG_TIME:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, new OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                time.setText(timeFormatter.format(c.getTime()));

            }
        }, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
    }

    return null;
}

// For date
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year1, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        year = year1;
        month = monthOfYear;
        day = dayOfMonth;
        // date.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateTime.getTime()));
        updateDisplay();
    }
};

public String getMonthForInt(int m) {
    String month = "invalid";
    DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
    String[] months = dfs.getMonths();
    if (m >= 0 && m <= 11) {
        month = months[m];
    }
    return month;
}

private void updateDisplay() {
    // String strDOB = month + 1 + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    // Log.v("strDOB : ", strDOB);

    intmonth = month;
    intday = day;
    intyear = year;

    strmonth = Integer.toString(intmonth);
    strday = Integer.toString(intday);
    stryear = Integer.toString(intyear);
    Log.v("month value", strmonth);
    Log.v("day value", strday);
    Log.v("year value", stryear);
    // int one=7;
    // Log.v("string limit",one.length());
    for (i = 0; i < intmonth; i++) {
        String strone = Integer.toString(intmonth);
        strone = months[i];
        // String intmonth=Integer.toString(months);
    }
    Log.v("month value", months[i].toString());
    date.setText(months[i] + "  " + day + "," + year);
}

 }
```

DemoActivity.class

```
public class DemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Creating an Alert Dialog Window */
    AlertDemo alert = new AlertDemo();

    /** Opening the Alert Dialog Window */
    alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "AlertDemo");
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not handling the AM/PM. Just put these lines of code...

```
int timeDifference=0; 
String ampm=splitampmtime[1]; 
if(ampm.matches("PM")){ 
timeDifference=12; 
} 

int splithour = timeDifference+Integer.parseInt(splitstrtime[0]); 
String[] splitsecond = splitstrtime[1].split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can add the check for AM and PM in your `save.setOnClickListener()` and change the value of hour accordingly:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        .....

        int splithour = Integer.parseInt(splitstrtime[0]); //10
        String[] splitsecond = splitstrtime[1].split(" "); //40, am

        Log.v("split str second", splitsecond[0]);
        int splitmin = Integer.parseInt(splitsecond[0]); //40

        if(splitsecond[1].equalsIgnoreCase("pm")) {
            splithour += 12;
        } else if(splitsecond[1].equalsIgnoreCase("am") && splithour == 12) {
            splithour = 0;
        }

        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: i used u logic but may be u r not getting my point. My alarm is showing me alert on 7pm if i set alarm for 7am,so how to clear that?

Comment: GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, hour, minute);       in this line if i pass 7am then alarm is not working if i pass 19pm then it works only for pm it works not for am dont know what is issue

Comment: I totally understand your point, tell me what the value of splithour hour which you pass in ;new GregorianCalendar(intyear, intmonth, intday, splithour, splitmin);'? If it is 7 then it will be called at 7am but for value 19 it will be called at 7pm.. my code is to change the hour value depending on AM/PM which you require in ur case

Comment: new GregorianCalendar(2013, 1, 11, 7, 20); if i pass values like this than i am facing a problem that  alarm alert is fired instantly after pressing the save button. and if i pass values like this new GregorianCalendar(2013, 1, 11, 19, 20)   than it works perfectly that means it is not taking am value

Comment: i used your code  it works but only for the pm purpose not for am because condition was like that if splithour==12 than only it will be converted into Zero

Comment: but for am splithour value will always be an 'AM' value i.e. less than 12 and greater than zero, isn't this the case?

Comment: hay u r point is write i am using 4.0 android emulator may be because of that it happning when i cheked same code in 2.3 device it works perfectly is thair any issue with 4.0 and above?

Comment: im pretty sure it doesn't have to do anything with android version. It should reflect the same behaviour on both... May be i can help more if you tell me the value you have when this line executes time.setText(timeFormatter.format(c.getTime())); in onTimeSet method- btw please do remember to mark my answer as correct if it helped u :)

Comment: values are  time value= 12:30 PM and time value= 12:32 AM

Comment: as I expected! it is working fine on both, you need to change the am/pm to make both times similar

Comment: not getting what u want to say? and i am sorry for previous mistake now i rectify that if i set 7.10am and in device thair is 7.05am then only it accept the alarm and if 7.05pm then alarm alert is fired instantly after pressing save button while setting alarm for 7.10 am. that means this not device problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please use:-

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + alarm_time,
                                operation);
```

in place of

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time, operation);
```

Read:-

```
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() is the current time in millis add the total time to skip from now to alarm in millis.
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to set the alarm using this method:

```
    /**
     * Set the Alarm
     *
     * @param context  the activity context
     * @param id       the alarm ID for this app
     * @param hour     the alarm hour
     * @param minute   the alarm minute
     * @param timeZone the timezone am = Calendar.AM or pm = Calendar.PM
     */
    public static void setAlarm(Context context, int id, int hour, int minute, int timeZone) {
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, timeZone);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PopupActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intent, 0);
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pIntent);
    }
```